# Start with angularjs 1 or 2?

Tags: angularjs

We are currently looking at moving our Rails Application over to a multi-app SPA and are looking at using Angular.  We are looking to port it over the next 6 - 12 months.  We really like the look of Angular.

It seems however that if we were to start with Angular 1, much of our code would be broken with Angular 2? However it seems that starting with Angular 2 would mean we were starting with essentially a brand new framework, less support for older browsers and so on.

Would anyone pick one over the other?

Matt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular vs Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114593/angular-vs-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

Though some people are using `Angular2` http://builtwithangular2.com/

`Angular2` recently came to beta you won't find many plugins right now and  the features might change before public release.

If it is a small app, you can start in `Angular2` build your custom features.

If it is a large app, I suggest you start with `Angular 1.5` and gradually migrate to `Angular2` using libraries like `ngUpgrade` etc.

Migration Guide: http://angularjs.blogspot.in/2015/08/angular-1-and-angular-2-coexistence.html