# How to easily switch to angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

So I learn angularJs not long ago, and I'm just getting started to get comfortable with it. But angular 2 is on the way and I have 2 major question:

1) Should I stop learning and working with angular 1 and start learning angular 2 instead?

I know a little about angular 2 and I know almost every thing has changed. So

2) What I know from angular 1 is any good in learning angular 2? Or should I learn angular 2 like it's a whole new framework? Is there any good way or guide to switch from angular 1 to 2?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114593/angular-vs-angular-2?rq=1

Comment: Angular (v2) and AngularJS (v1) have 7 characters in common. The rest is totally different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I learn angularJs not long ago

Then, this is the perfect time to start learning Angular 2, too. Starting a new language version while you have not already spend a lot of time on another one is a good choice in my opinion. However since Angular 2 is still in RC you should not completely leave learning Angular 1.x and start with Angular 2.

> 1) Should I stop learning and working with angular 1 and start
>   learning angular 2 instead?

No, even though the future of Angular framework seems to be Angular 2, this version is still in RC and building large apps using it would be a high risk.Angular 1.x compared to Angular 2 is more stable on this aspect. Angular 2 is constantly evolving, every few weeks there are totally new concepts included.
You should not stop learning Angular 1.x but, you should start learning Angular 2, too.

> 2) What I know from angular 1 is any good in learning angular 2?

Although there are a lot of changes like between these versions they still have similarities.For instance, in Angular 2 the concept of controllers does not exist, but they use Components. `ng-if` and `ng-for` directives from Angular 1.x look like `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` in Angular 2.  The best resource to compare the two versions is their official website which you can find here [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/a1-a2-quick-reference.html).

> Is there any good way or guide to switch from angular 1 to 2?

Although you can still find very useful information about upgrading from Angular 1.x to Angular 2 on their [official website](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html)
 I would suggest that you treat Angular 2 as a completely new framework and start it from zero.Also the knowledge you already have about Angular 1.x will be helpful since there are concepts that have not changed that much. There are plenty of tutorials available online for free that you could use.

My favorite YouTube playlists are:

- [Angular 2 Start](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLillGF-RfqbbZnAJlEzttBrbkAO27U_hd)
- [Angular 2 Basics Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyfY5aqbLNI&index=5&list=PL55RiY5tL51qIb5VW2ywbT12UZeqmzBAu)
- [Build Angular 2 Weather App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7EhBTPlQkk&list=PL55RiY5tL51rslbEyCA6Gm2mRQ9VJxAYh)

Comment: I will suggest 1 more playlist here, Learn Angular2 step by step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DXkozJ7mp0&list=PLFtLsSgifot9PrUPDWcvH3mBVjNkw9wzs

Answer (score 1):

Well , This is the major question for all angular2 beginners who knows angular1 ... , 
**Just imagine you don't know angularjs1 then Definitely you are more comfortable with angular2** ... The thing is Angular is the future that is the unwritten truth ... Definitely Angular1 is not going to die ...but It may be loose from the competition ... You have to consider following things to choose angular2 ...

- Type Script (Great Coding Structure)
- Componets (Great Library Support )
- Rich Third party library Support
- Creator the Giant (Google )

**Finally You have to go with the future ... (Angular2)**