# Why I decided to start with AngularJS instead of Angular 2

Tags: angularjs

I am clarifying this question after I have been developing SPA for the past 5 months using AngualrJS. In the beginning, I was researching if I should start with Angular 2 instead.

During my research, I came across this article:

https://angular.jsnews.io/why-learning-angular-2-was-excruciating/

https://hackernoon.com/why-learning-angular-2-was-excruciating-d50dc28acc8a

I then realized that I have faced a lot of the issues referenced in that article.

Also, when I started with the offical Angular websites https://angularjs.org/ and https://angular.io/ and followed the recommendation:

[image: Angular Official Website Recommendation]

I spent several days using the various resources learning Angular 2 based on the above websites and faced a lot of difficulties. I remember I started with this 5 MIN QUICKSTART:

http://a2.hubwiz.com/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Which took me several hours to complete, with several scary error messages in red color.

Later, I started using other resources such as w3schools.com and stackoverflow.com, and I see mostly reference to script tag as follows:

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>`

Which is clear that it was referencing AngularJS. Finally, I realized that learning Angular 2 to start taking advantage of the newly added feature, will cost me a lot of time and effort. Finally, I decided to stay with AngularJS especially I was able to find a solution to each and every business requirement for the complex Forms Application Development I was working on.

Also, I read the other post which is suggested as an answer for my question. What is mentioned there is that Angular 2 is in developer preview:

[image: Angular 2 is in developer preview]

However, the official websites doesn't mention that. So, the post above is not relevant anymore and I cannot depend on it.

So my recommendation, if you have enough time to spend in learning Angular 2 and deal with the issues that might show-up then of course this is the recommended path, otherwise, best to stay with AngualrJS.

Tarek

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular vs Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114593/angular-vs-angular-2)

Comment: How can you be confused when the version number is right there in the URL?  Also, Angular2 is still in pre-release status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using angular 1 exactly 1.4.8. it's in the link. Most of the tutorials  on the internet for angular 1 that's why everything works ok for you.unless you specify angular 2 in the search you will get angular 1 tutorials that's cause angular 2 is pretty new

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not sure why downgrading the question? I checked other questions, and didn't get answer for my question.