# Generalize the save and get in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have the following http requests:

```
save(data: Object, options: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    let authHeader = 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': authHeader, 'controllerAction': 'Test' });
    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let url = this.toURL(undefined);
    // let observable = this.http.post(url, data).map(this.extractData);
    let observable = this.http.post(url, data, requestOptions).map(this.extractData);
    return observable;
}

ajax(): Observable<any> {
    let authHeader = 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': authHeader, 'controllerAction': 'Test' });
    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let url = this.toURL(undefined);
    let http = this.method == 'GET' ? this.http.get(url, requestOptions) : this.http.get(url);

    let observable = http.map(this.extractData);
    this.reset();
    return observable;
}
```

As you can see the both the methods have some variables in common. How to make the variable generic so that I can call it only once? I have an init function, should I put there?

Comment: You create a class `class MyCustomHttp extends Http { ...}`and use it instead of `Http` and add the common parts there. There are several examples posted as answers already.

Comment: Thanks man. I figured out already as per your answer

Comment: Glad to hear. If you found an answer with a helpful solution it would be great to mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular vs Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114593/angular-vs-angular-2)