# What major diffrences we can found between Angularjs and Angularjs 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular

Want to know the difference between the two angular programming languages,is learnt angualrjs will help in learning angular2 while switching

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114593/angular-vs-angular-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of differences between these two. you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114593/angular-vs-angular-2#answer-34116329) to learn about differences of those two. If you can learn both of angular 2 and angular JS it will be great. In next few years most of the companies will move to their systems from angularjs to angular 2, So knowing both of these will be a plus point.