# Is there a difference between ng-model and NgModel in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

In Angular 2.x, is there a difference between ng-model and NgModel in Angular 2? Referring to following Angular documentation

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html

It uses terminology `[(ng-model)]="property"` to explain two-way data binding. Just below this, it uses the example using NgModel (instead of ng-model)

```
<input [(ngModel)]="hero.name">
```

I am confused if this is a typo (I guess not!).

Comment: There is no difference between them.

Comment: `ng-model` is in angularjs (v1.x) and `ngModel` is in angular 2+.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114593/angular-vs-angular-2

Comment: I can't find any occurrence of ng-model in the page you linked to.

Comment: There is a pic just under Data Binding section.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a bug. You should submit an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no difference, but the one in Angular gives you more flexibility than the one in AngularJS.

`[(` in Angular is signalling a two-way data binding. Theoretically you could only bind to an event (`(ngModel)`) or to a value (`[ngModel]`). This gives you the ability to handle changes going down in a different way than changes coming up. With AngularJS you do not have that flexibility.

But just to sum up, `ng-model` is equal to `[(ngModel)]`.

Comment: Are you saying I can use any one of them in the code? They are interchangeable in the code.

Comment: No. You can use ``ng-model`` with AngularJS and ``[(ngModel)]`` with Angular (v2+). It depends on which one you want to use. They are completely different from each other.

Comment: thank you for clarifying the relationship between `ng-model` and `[(ng-model)]` and the discrepancies between Angular and AngularJS relating to this directive

Answer (score 9):

`[` is component bind to view . `(` is view bind to component . ngModel is two way binding so this use this syntax `[(` . And there is no differentce beetween `[(ngModel])` in angular2+ and `ng-model` in angular1