# how to upgrade codebase ionic v1 to ionic v3

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cross-platform

I am facing issue in ionic 1 and this framework is deprecated. how to upgrade ionic 1 to ionic 3 without huge modifying in codebase. anyone help in this

Note: ionic build ios those command all are not working

[image]

Advance Thanks

Comment: do you mean updating cordova platform or project framework?

Comment: I am using cordova  for ionic mobile application. I am beginner to create

Comment: There is a migration guide available here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/migration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> without huge modifying in codebase

This is not going to be possible.

Ionic 1 to 2/3 is a large jump from AngularJS to Angular2, which requires a switch to typescript and other fundamental framework alterations.

[Here is a good post about AngularJS vs Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34116329/5779280)

[Here is a good write up](http://ionicframework.com/files/Ionic2Migration.pdf) for the migration from Ionic 1 to Ionic 2 that should help.

Then once that's done, the [migration from 2 to 3](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-2017-04-05) is not that big of a leap.