# how to getrid of ionic v1 deprecation error issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, cross-platform

I am getting ionic v1 deprecation error issue. so it's not working

```
ionic build ios
ionic emulate android
```

Those basic commands are not working. How to overcome this issue.

Note: I have ionic v1 application so with do huge modification how to upgrade or use older version .

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is your ionic cli version? output of `ionic info`

Comment: @suraj: i added image . please check

Answer (score 0):

You have the latest ionic cli version (3.x). The error does not seem to be related to project version.

The command to build and run is changed to:

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

and

```
ionic cordova emulate ios
```

You may need to use sudo with your commands.

Check [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/)

Comment: Is there any way to degrade the ionic version 1.

Comment: your project? or the cli? maybe this will be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521876/how-to-upgrade-codebase-ionic-v1-to-ionic-v3