# Setting col-* value dynamically from object value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic Framework and its grid system (similar to Bootstrap). However, I believe my question is more AngularJS than Ionic components.

I have the following:

```
 <ion-col *ngFor="let col of row.cols"></ion-col>
```

Note that I must set values for each col dynamically so in case `col.size === 2` the above must be rendered as:

```
 <ion-col *ngFor="let col of row.cols" col-2></ion-col>
```

One way is to set all cols in advance and call *ngIfs on whichever size I want which seems like an overkill for something simpler. I have also tried to do this:
`<ion-col *ngFor="let col of row.cols" [attr.col-2]="col.size === 2"></ion-col>` With zero luck.

Possible values could be from `1 to 12`.
Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: could you share some sample data for cols

Comment: Which do you mean, [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or [Angular](https://angular.io/)?

Comment: @user1027620 is it same thing to do <ion-col *ngFor="let col of row.cols" class="col-2"></ion-col> or not the same?

Comment: @user1027620 I just realized I didn't quite understand what `col.size` means. Could you please clarify it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[dynamic-col]'
})

export class DynamicColDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input('dynamic-col') value: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._renderer.setElementAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'col-' + this.value, '');
  }
}
```

And then:

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let col of row.cols; let i = index" dynamic-col="{{i}}"></ion-col>
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using `ng-container`'s? They could be perfect as they don't display in the DOM.

This will still create all of your `ion-col`'s as if they were generated using your original code but allow you to add attributes to the root element of the loop.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let col of row.cols">
    <ion-col col-{{col.col-size}}></ion-col>
</ng-container>
```

---

If you have the array below:

```
{
  "rows": {
    "cols": {
      {
        "col-size": "2"
      },
      {
        "col-size": "4"
      },
      {
        "col-size": "6"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The HTML then output is like below:

```
<ion-col col-2></ion-col>
<ion-col col-4></ion-col>
<ion-col col-6></ion-col>
```

- [Tutorial On `ng-container`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue)

Comment: This seemed the most easy & neat solution, but it didn't work for me - and i tried also in few variation

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in typescript and bind to the `innerHtml` attribute:

**component.ts:**

```
  rows = {
    cols: [
      { "size": "1" },
      { "size": "3" },
      { "size": "5" }
    ]
  }
  html: string = '';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.rows.cols.map((col) => {
      this.html += '<ion-col class="col" col-' + col.size + '></ion-col>'
    });
  }
  ...
```

**component.html:**

```
  <div [innerHTML]="html | safeHtml"></div>
  ...
```

*using pipe to disable Angular’s built-in sanitization.*

**safeHtml.pipe.ts:**

```
@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class Safe {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustXxx(style); - see DomSanitizer docs
  }
}
```

See also:

- [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation)
- [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37076868/4899523)
- [Angular safe pipe implementation to bypass DomSanitizer stripping out content](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b)
- [Angular DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you asked for AngularJS solution, but in your code you demonstrated Angular example instead. I want to make sure you understand that [they are very different from each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114593/angularjs-vs-angular).

---

The following code is taken from the project of my chess game, **using AngularJS**:

> HTML Template

```
<main class="container">
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary center" ng-click="startGame()">Start Chess</button>
    </div>
    <div class="game-board center">
        <div class="game-board-row" ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <div class="game-board-grid" ng-repeat="col in cols" data-x="{{ col }}" data-y="{{ row }}" ng-click="click(this);">
                <div class="piece" data-text-color="{{ game.data.grids[row][col].value.group }}" data-bg-color="game.data.grids[row][col].occupied">{{ game.data.grids[row][col].value.text }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

> JavaScript (AngularJS)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let app = angular.module('game', []);
    app.run(($rootScope) => {
        $rootScope.rows = ['0', '1', '2', '3'];
        $rootScope.cols = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'];
    });
</script>
```

If you are **using Angular** instead, change the code into the following style:

> HTML Template

```
<main class="container">
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary center" (click)="startGame()">Start Chess</button>
    </div>
    <div class="game-board center">
        <div class="game-board-row" *ngFor="row in rows">
            <div class="game-board-grid" *ngFor="col in cols" [data-x]="col" [data-y]="row" (click)="click(this);">
                <div class="piece" [data-text-color]="game.data.grids[row][col].value.group" [data-bg-color]="game.data.grids[row][col].occupied">{{ game.data.grids[row][col].value.text }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

> JavaScript (Angular)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game',
  templateUrl: './game.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game.component.scss']
})
export class GameComponent implements OnInit {

  rows = ['0', '1', '2', '3'];
  cols = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

---

When you want to select those grids with *CSS*, you need [*attribute selector*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)! For example:

```
[data-x="1"][data-y="2"] {
    /* This selects the grid located at (1, 2) */
}
```