# Angular generated project, unresponsive controller

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-controller

I'm sorry for the broad question but I'm having a hard time pin pointing my problem.
I use the "ng new" command to generate a new angular project, but when i try to utilize controller in the project they remain unresponsive.
To assure it was not my code it took a code block from: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_events.asp (The ng-click Directive example 2) can also be seen below:

when running this code in a single index.html file the angular controller is responsive and the count changes on my screen, when clicked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <button ng-click="myFunction()">Click me!</button>
        <p>{{ count }}</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.count = 0;
            $scope.myFunction = function () {
                $scope.count++;
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but when inserting the code in my application, formatted basically the same but without the "DOCTYPE", "html" & "script src=..." tags (can be seen below) the application becomes unresponsive.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <button ng-click="myFunction()">Click me!</button>
    <p>COUNT:</p>
    <p>{{ count }}</p> 
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.count = 0;
        $scope.myFunction = function () {
            $scope.count++;
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'm not sure what other files can be of interest to solving this problem but please write and i will provide them, but currently i have made no other controllers, and the above mentioned .html file is in a sub component of the app.component.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is the current angular won't support the ng-click and all don't refer the w3schools it's an outdated tutorial, I would suggest you go with the https://angular.io/ (angular's official documentation)

Coming to your problem angular 2+ has a different syntax no controllers so it won't work

Your app.component.html should be:

```
<div>
    <button (click)="myFunction()">Click me!</button>
    <p>{{ count }}</p>
</div>
```

Your app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

    public count    :    number    =    0;

    constructor() {}

    public myFunction() {
        this.count  =    this.count + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ng new` command does not generate angularjs app. It generate Angular App, which is very different:

- Angular is written in Typescript ( most of the time ), as Angular is written in Javascript ( most of the time )
- Angular is under active developpement ( version 9 as of this writing ), and Angularjs is in long term support until June 30, 2021.
- Angular make use of most of the new browser feature as AngularJs is stuck with old compatibility issue.
- Many more things, [check out this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114593/angularjs-vs-angular)

In your case, you are following an angularjs tutorial. This cannot apply to your context.

You still can use angularjs, but it is recommended to migrate to Angular. If you still wish to create an angularJS app, you can follow that tutorial with no problem. However, you cannot create a new app using the `ng new`.

If, however, you are looking for an Angular tutorial, I suggest looking into their [Hero tutorial](https://angular.io/start) which is very well made and easy to understand.